# Spring boot : Correct the classpath of your application

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, boot

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters and org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding below maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and also by removing the version tag 5.2.3.RELEASE from the below dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Remove that `spring-web` dependency as that is already included in the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. You are trying to outsmart the starters you are using.